# System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: apex, soql

> System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException:
>   ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I am getting above exception for the SOQL query,

```
[SELECT 
    BuyingCenter__c bcId, Offering__c offId, count(Id) cnt,
    SUM(Opportunity__r.amount) amt, SUM(Opportunity__r.expectedrevenue) exptAmt,
    Grouping(BuyingCenter__c) bcGrp, Grouping(Offering__c) offGrp
FROM 
    DFLSOpportunity_Extension__c 
WHERE 
    (Opportunity__r.AccountId = '0010o00002BjidaAAB' OR Opportunity__r.Account.KeyAccount__c = '0010o00002BjidaAAB') 
    AND Opportunity__r.isClosed = false 
GROUP BY
    CUBE (BuyingCenter__c, Offering__c) 
LIMIT 50000]
```

I didn't get anything which will help to resolve this issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

To mirror this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_cube.htm):

```
SELECT Type, BillingCountry,
    GROUPING(Type) grpType, GROUPING(BillingCountry) grpCty,
    COUNT(id) accts
FROM Account
GROUP BY CUBE(Type, BillingCountry)
ORDER BY GROUPING(Type), GROUPING(BillingCountry)
```

your query would need to start like this:

```
SELECT GROUPING(BuyingCenter__c) bcId, GROUPING(Offering__c) offId, ...
```

so try this.

(The error is being generated by the underlying Oracle database so the Salesforce query engine.)

**PS**

Do you have the API version of the calling class set to 45.0?

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I have tried your solution, but it's giving the same error.

Comment: @yogeshshete OK, thought it was worth a try. Just added  PS to make sure the calling class API version is the latest version too.

Comment: Thanks, Keith. I had raised a case to Salesforce support regarding this. They have found this is an internal platform bug (BUG with id W-6109724). It will resolve soon.